# IOUtils.copy up to specified length

Tags: java, stream, apache-commons

I noticed there doesn't seem to be a way to specify a length of bytes for the copy method. `copyLarge(InputStream input, OutputStream output, long inputOffset, long length)` is basically what I'm looking for, but the API asserts this is meant for files over 2GB, which is not necessarily the case for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`copyLarge(InputStream input, OutputStream output, long inputOffset, long length)` is using copy buffer of 4kb. So you can use it also for smaller files.

Comment: Well that's good to hear. The method description is a bit misleading.